# Parse Numeric Ranges in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, gaps-and-islands

I would like to produce a string containing some parsed numeric ranges.

I have a table with some data

```
b_id,s_id
1,50
1,51
1,53
1,61
1,62
1,63
2,91
2,95
2,96
2,97
```

Using only SQL in PostgreSQL, how could I produce this output:

```
b_id,s_seqs
1,"50-51,53,61-63"
2,"91,95-97"
```

How on earth do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select b_id, string_agg(seq, ',' order by seq_no) as s_seqs
from (
    select 
        b_id, seq_no,
        replace(regexp_replace(string_agg(s_id::text, ','), ',.+,', '-'), ',', '-') seq
    from (
        select 
            b_id, s_id, 
            sum(mark) over w as seq_no
        from (
            select 
                b_id, s_id, 
                (s_id- 1 <> lag(s_id, 1, s_id) over w)::int as mark
            from my_table
            window w as (partition by b_id order by s_id)
            ) s
        window w as (partition by b_id order by s_id)
        ) s
    group by 1, 2
    ) s
group by 1;
```

[Here you can find](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=c42e14f74b0f4c8bc5c944c8d2c2e64d) a step-by-step analyse from the innermost query towards the outside.

Comment: Please tell me your mailing address so I can send you an unbelievable amount of beer. Thank you. Not the first time you've saved me, and while I am trying to learn, I'm not "there" yet.

Comment: Store it in a cold place and drink to my health (not everything at once!)